# how to add gridview row after copy into row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a program that i want to copy a top cell into current cell when i press F7,but the problem is until the user did not type anything the gridview does not add the row,the question is : how can i add row when the user pressed the F7 and notice that if the user pressed anything into gridview and then pressed the F7,gridview will have two empty row,how can i manage it?[image]

[image]

this is the code that i use to copy the source cell value into destination cell when user pressed F7 :

```
int rowno = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1;
int cellno = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

if (rowno >= 0 && cellno >= 0)
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[rowno].Cells[cellno].Value;
```

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question? It is difficult to understand.

Comment: gridview automatically add a row after the user type on it,but if i add data programmatically into a cell,like copy the top cell into current cell,the gridview didnot add new row.

Comment: If you are using winform then it should be `datagridview` instead of `GridView`?

Comment: yes it is datagridview,you are right.

Comment: try using `datagridview.Rows.Add(1);` when you programmatically add data to cell.

Comment: its ok,but when i add a row and then user type into next cell,datagridview will add another row so then we have two empty row.

Comment: Add code in the question. This will be easy to identify issue.

Comment: so you want to add row programmatically only?

Comment: no,i'm looking for a way that when user use F7 for a cell and then type in another cell in row,just add one new row into datagridview

Comment: See below mentioned solution to your issue. Tell me if it works?

Comment: so,if user did not use F7 to copy the value,then datagridview does not add new row.my problem is to understand that a new row is added or not.

Answer (score 0):

Set [DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows) to `false`. This will restrict automatically adding of new row when cell value become dirty.

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

However programmatically you can add rows using `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1)` etc.

Comment: so,if user did not use F7 to copy the value,then datagridview does not add new row.my problem is to understand that a new row is added or not.

Comment: You can check rows count, to know whether new row added or not.